# GML layer is displying in changed rotation

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver, gml, web-feature-service

I created GML  WFS layer from Geo-server and using in Open Layer 3,but in output showing map rotations are changed .On my PC showing the GML but in fiddle doesn't showing output.Is there any mistake in my code . I want to create GML or GML2 format using  WFS layer .I have done little bit bit code here . Please help me Thanks. this is GML2 URL `http://localhost/geoserver/topp/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=topp:states&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=text%2Fxml%3B%20subtype%3Dgml%2F2.1.2`
 This is fiddle URL https://jsfiddle.net/seema30/cubtvykw/.

Comment: is there any response from GeoServer? are you really running on port 80 and not 8080? is there a CORs issue which would work locally but not remotly

Comment: getting response from Geo-server.I running on port 80,it works properly there is no issue but showing only rotation  changed,like if i give lat/long then return long/lat.and I am using wfs version 1.0.0 so is there any way to change version in Geo-server. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Actually the problem only in version .In WFS version 1.0.0 by default returns log/lat,if you give BBOX, extent  or anything but still not change projection.I just used the version of wfs 1.1.0 ,in this version returns proper projection(lat/log).Thanks